# Problema com animação no Menu

Tags: javascript, css3

Estou tentando criar um menu simples, com uma animação que ao clicar no ícone as opções do menu aparece, caso click novamente no ícones elas somem.

Só consegui ate agora, que as opções aparecem quando ícone é clicado, porem ao final do click as opções somem novamente

O Código esta em css puro, pois esse tipo de animação não sei fazer em Javascript

Codigo HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <i class="fas fa-sliders-h icone" id="icone"></i>
    <div class="nav">
        <li class="li" id="li"><a href="form.html" target="_black" class="link">Form <hr></a></li>
        <li class="li"><a href="#" class="link">Contact<hr></a></li>
        <li class="li"><a href="#" class="link">Article<hr></a></li>
    </div>              
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav li {opacity: 0;}
.nav{background: transparent; height: 50px; border:1px solid black;}

.icone{position: absolute; display: inline; color:white; font-size: 1.5em; text-align: left; width: 60px;}
.icone:active ~ .nav li{animation:Menu 0.1s; animation-fill-mode: forwards;}

@keyFrames Menu{
    80%{text-align: right;}
    90%{text-align: center;}
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Jovem, que tipo de animação vc queria? Olhando o seu código não consegui entender direito qual efeito que vc quer obter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um exemplo só para deixar registrado utilizando Javascript:

```js
var lis = document.getElementsByClassName("li");

for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  lis[i].style.display = 'none';
}

document.getElementById('icone').addEventListener('click', function() {
  
    setTimeout(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
        if (lis[i].style.display == "none") {
          lis[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
          lis[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }, 500);
})
```

```css
.nav {
  background: transparent;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: right;
}

.icone {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: left;
  width: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <i class="fas fa-sliders-h icone" id="icone">Icone</i>
  <div class="nav">
    <li class="li" id="li">
      <a href="#" class="link">Form</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li">
      <a href="#" class="link">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li">
      <a href="#" class="link">Article</a>
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Porem queria dar um pequeno delay, para executar a funçao addEventListener. Com javascript puro é possível fazer?

Comment: Você diz dar um **delay** na animação, clicar no ícone e demorar a aparecer as lis é isto?

Comment: Exatamente isso

Comment: Editei a resposta colocando um timeout de 500 ms.

Answer (score 2):

Cara seu código tinha alguns pequenos erros tanto no CSS quanto HTML. Vou te dar uma explicação do seu problema, e uma forma de resolve-lo apenas com CSS e HTML

No CSS a pseudo classe `:active` é aplicada apenas quando vc faz o "press" clicando no elemento, tão logo vc solta o botão do mouse o estado `:active` é removido, por isso vc via a animação rapidamente e depois ela sumia.

Para resolver esse problema vc precisei ajustar o HTML, eu coloquei o seu ícone dentro de uma `label` com um `for` para um `checkbox` que fica oculto com `display:none`. Quando vc clica na `label` vc muda o estado desse `checkbox` oculto para `:checked` e ele abre o menu com a animação, quando vc clica novamente na `label` ele tira o estado `:checked` do `checkbox` e o menu some. Outra coisa, agora cloque os estilos da classe `.icone` na `label` apenas, tipo `label {csss}`.

*Apesar disso vejo que vc precisa fazer muitos ajustes de CSS ai para ficar legal, o próprio exemplo não está perfeito pq eu não quis mexer de mais no CSS e mudei o mínimo apenas para ele funcionar, mas vc precisa estudar mais sobre os `positions`, `margins` e `paddings` para usa-los da forma mais adequada*

Veja o código para entender melhor, comentei no código onde é para vc ter mais atenção e ver o que mudei.

**OBS:** Toda `LI` deve ser filho de uma `UL` ou `OL`, então eu arrumei isso no seu HTML, leia a documentação sobre as Listas Ordenadas e Não Ordenadas aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

```css
.nav ul {
    opacity: 0;
}

.nav {
    background: transparent;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

label {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    color: gray;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: left;
    width: 60px;
}

/* agora é quando o btn está com estado :checked que a animação é aplicada */
#btn:checked~.nav ul  {
    animation: Menu 0.1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyFrames Menu {
    80% {
        text-align: right;
    }

    90% {
        text-align: center;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
#btn {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">


<div class="header">
<!-- coloquei o ícone dentro da label, com um for = para o ID do input-checkbox abaixo -->
    <label for="btn"><i class="fas fa-sliders-h icone" id="icone"></i></label>
<!-- quando esse inpute é :checked ele ativa a animação do menu -->
    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="btn">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="li" id="li">
                <a href="form.html" target="_black" class="link">Form
                    <hr>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="li">
                <a href="#" class="link">Contact
                    <hr>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="li">
                <a href="#" class="link">Article
                    <hr>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

É possível fazer essa animação com JavaScript puro, agora há alguns problemas no seu HTML. Um deles é o atributo `target`: em vez de `_blank` você colocou "_black". Outro são as `<li>` sem `<ul>`, o que é semanticamente incorreto. E em vez de usar `<hr>`, sugiro aplicar uma borda inferior nos itens do menu. Isso porque o `<hr>` é um elemento que pode variar visualmente em cada navegador e pela especificação HTML5, deve ser usado para separar separar assuntos, como num texto, por exemplo.

Veja como fica:

```js
var el = document.querySelector(".nav ul");
var lis = document.querySelectorAll(".nav a");

// função que anima as <li>
function animaLi(ini, fim, atu){

   atu -= 4;
   var e = atu/100;
   var d = fim-ini;
   d *= e;
   d += ini;

   for(var x=0; x<lis.length; x++){
      lis[x].style.left = d+"%";
      lis[x].style.transform = "translateX(-"+d+"%)";
   }
   
   if(atu > 0){
   
      window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
         animaLi(ini, fim, atu);
      });
      
   }

}

// função que anima o menu
function anima(ini, fim, atu, dis){

   atu += 4;
   var e = atu/100;
   var d = fim-ini;
   d *= e;
   d += ini;
   el.style.opacity = d;

   if(atu < 100){
   
      window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
         anima(ini, fim, atu, dis);
      });
      
      if(atu >= 20 && !dis) animaLi(50, 150, 50);
      
   }else{

      if(dis) el.style.display = "none";
      for(var x=0; x<lis.length; x++){
         lis[x].style.left = "100%";
         lis[x].style.transform = "translateX(-100%)";
      }

   }
}

// captura o click no ícone
document.querySelector(".icone").onclick = function(){
   
   if(el.style.display != "block"){
      el.style.display = "block";
      anima(0, 1, 0); // chama a função para mostrar o menu
   }else{
      anima(1, 0, 1, 1); // chama a função para esconder o menu
   }

}
```

```css
.nav{
   background: transparent;
   height: 50px;
   border: 1px solid black;
}

.nav ul, .nav li{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
}

.nav ul{
   opacity: 0;
   display: none;
}

.nav li{
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
   padding: 10px 0;
}

.nav a{
   position: relative;
   left: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
   transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.icone{
   position: absolute;
   font-size: 1.5em;
   text-align: left;
   width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="header">
    <i class="fas fa-sliders-h icone" id="icone"></i>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="li" id="li"><a href="form.html" target="_blank" class="link">Form</a></li>
        <li class="li"><a href="#" class="link">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="li"><a href="#" class="link">Article</a></li><br>
      </ul>
    </div>              
</div>
```